# How can I update the contents of a list with data from another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of two properties named `Kanjis` :

[image]

and I would like to use that to update the contents of another list named `PhraseSources`

```
public class PhraseSource
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int PhraseNum { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string Kanji { get; set; }
    public string WordType { get; set; }
    public string FrequencyA { get; set; }
}
```

by matching together Kanji > Text and updating FrequencyA with Code

Is this something that can be done with LINQ or is there a better to way to do this by iterating through each of the rows of the phraseSource, checking for a matching entry in Kanjis and doing an update that way?

**Here's the code suggested by Salva that I tried:**

```
(from sa in source
         join d in psDb on sa.Text equals d.Kanji
         let temp = d.FrequencyA = sa.Code
         select 0).ToList();
```

gives error:

> ApplyFrequency.cs(14,14): Error CS1941: The type of one of the
>   expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in
>   the call to 'Join'. (CS1941) (Download)

```
 source.Join(psDb, s => s.Text, d => d.Kanji, (s, d) => d.FrequencyA = s.Code).ToList();
```

gives error:

> ApplyFrequency.cs(21,21): Error CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'Enumerable.Join(IEnumerable,
>   IEnumerable, Func, Func,
>   Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly. (CS0411) (Download)

Notes:

I had to use this code as I was asked to change FrequencyA to an int:

```
var source = original
                    .Select(x => new 
                    {
                        Text = x.Text,
                        Code = Convert.ToInt32(x.Code.Substring(2))
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: You can [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) the lists, iterate the result and update it.

Comment: @Alan2 show declaration of `source` and `psDb` variables and their types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via single linq **query syntax**:

```
var source = new List<TextCodeClass>();
var dest = new List<PhraseSource>();

(from s in source
 join d in dest on s.Text equals d.Kanji 
 let temp = d.FrequencyA = s.Code.ToString()
 select 0).ToList();
```

or via **method syntax**:

```
source.Join(dest, s => s.Text, d => d.Kanji, (s, d) => d.FrequencyA = s.Code.ToString())
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Hello Slava,  What's the name for the format that you use with from and join ?

Comment: @Alan2, it is linq query syntax

Comment: Hi Slava, I'm still learning about LINQ. It seems very powerful. Does the query syntax have another form? I didn't see it written like that before with LINQ. Is it possible to write in the . form or are there some queries that must be written with from, in and join like you did?

Comment: @Alan2 you can read more about LINQ query syntax and LINQ method syntax in this link. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-query-syntax. What you are used to seeing is probably the LINQ method syntax.

Comment: @Alan2, yes you can also use method syntax. Look at updated answer.

Comment: Hi Slava, I thought the code was working okay but when I try to implement I get errors. I will update the question to show these as there's not enough space in the comments.

Comment: @Alan2, you should create `source` with type `List<TextCodeClass>` from `IEnumerator` by itrerating it and then use `source` as shown above.

Comment: Hi Salva, I have include the code that creates source there is ToList() at the end of that code.  Can you explain what you mean when you say "from IEnumerator".  Should I be doing it differently? Thank you

Comment: @Alan2, problem is `Code` has `int` type and `FrequencyA` is `string`, so you should cast one field to another (i.e. calling `.ToString()`)

Answer (score 1):

You can update list through LINQ only. The closest you could get is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  List<SomeClass> scl = new List<SomeClass>();
  List<OtherClass> ocl = new List<OtherClass>();

  foreach (var item in scl)
    item.FrequencyA = ocl.Where(i => i.Text == item.Kanji).FirstOrDefault()?.Code ?? null;
}

// sample classes that reflect relevant properties
public class SomeClass
{
  public string FrequencyA { get; set; }
  public string Kanji { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Michal,  did you mean "You cannot update .. " in your answer?  Slava suggested a LINQ solution so I am a bit confused as to if it can be done or not and the performance implications of one method or other.  Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend having `ocl` a `HashSet` and not a list, and if the `Text` is unique then even better `Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: @GiladGreen Thanks for remark, but collections used are just for sake of presenting solution :)

Comment: @Alan2 Well, maybe it's possible with query syntax of LINQ. I wasn't aware of that